# How does precedence between multiple provider takes place in Google Guice?

Tags: java, guice

I am trying Google Guice as Dependency Injection framework for my new project and shifting from spring.
I have to write multiple providers using @Provides, where instance created from one provider will be used as an input to other providers in the separate modules (sometimes the same module). 
For binding the instance generated from the module, I am using Guice's

```
@BindingAnnotation
```

to create a custom annotation.

I just wanted to know how does the precedence works in Google Guice?

Like in spring we had a @Dependson annotation for bean creation, is there an alternative in Guice or Guice smart enough to generate a dependency graph by itself?

Does Binding the instances of providers using annotation created from @BindingAnnotation enough?

Comment: @SamuelRobert wrong! Just wrong! What are your source to tell such a fake information?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, perhaps due to my unfamiliarity with Spring.  Guice is definitely smart enough to figure out the dependency graph itself, that's what it's for!

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are asking (but I'll attempt to answer anyway), and it's been enough time that you might have an answer yourself. So you may be able to add clarification now, or self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

> [is] Guice smart enough to generate a dependency graph by itself?

I'm not familiar with Spring, but my gut-feeling is **Yes**.

> Does Binding the instances of providers using annotation created from
>   @BindingAnnotation enough?

As long as the provider has been annotated as providing something (using `@Provides`), Guice will use that annotation as a default, unless otherwise overridden inside a module.

However, using BindingAnnotations **does** include some code in a Module to bind it together,

https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations

```
bind(CreditCardProcessor.class)
    .annotatedWith(PayPal.class)
    .to(PayPalCreditCardProcessor.class);
```

So I suspect that Binding Annotations based annotations have stronger strength then `@Provides` and as long as you have the counterpart in the module, is more then enough to bind your providers together.